# Invalid association. Make sure that accepts_nested_attributes_for is used for

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have a check_in (of a reservation) form, in which at some point I want to have a nested form to add room_requests to it:

```
= nested_form_for @reservation, url: check_in_check_in_path, method: 'put' do |f|
  = f.fields_for :guests do |guest_form|
    = label_tag t('users.new.first_name'), nil,  class: 'grey h2 input-label'
    = guest_form.text_field(:first_name, class: 'check-in-input')
    (...)
  = f.link_to_add "Add guest", :guests

  = f.fields_for :room_requests do |room_form|
    = label_tag nil, t('rooms.new.category'), class: 'grey h2'
    = room_form.select(:room_category_id, current_hotel.room_categories.collect {|p| [ p.category, p.id, rate: p.base_rate ] }, {}, class: 'dropdown form-input category-dropdown')
  (...)
  = f.link_to_add "Add room request", :room_requests
```

From the above code, the "Add guest" button works, but the "Add room request" does not.

From the reservation model:

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :guests
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :guests, allow_destroy: false
  has_many :room_requests, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :reservation
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :room_requests, allow_destroy: true
end
```

And the reservation_controller.rb:

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
  def reservation_params
    params.require(:reservation).permit(
    :start_date, :end_date, :status, :tag_list, :sales_channel_id,
    :comments, :room_category_id, :client_id,
    client_attributes: [:id, :hotel_id, :first_name, :last_name, :address, :country,
                        :doc_type, :doc_number, :email, :phone, :city],
    room_requests_attributes: [:id, :adults, :children, :room_category_id, :hotel_id,
                               :price,  :rate_id, :room_id, :_destroy],
    guests_attributes: [:id, :first_name, :last_name, :nationality, :room_request_id,
                        :doc_type, :doc_number])
  end
end
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Anything within the (...) that could be helpful here?

Comment: I could type it all, but it's pretty large. It has other fields of the form for the guests and the room_requests

Comment: Since nested_form is using jQuery to copy the form blueprint, and the fact that the guest form is working properly, it makes me think that something within the room requests form is interfering or causing an issue.

I tested locally with a similar layout that you posted and it worked fine with the select.

I would inspect the element and see if anything comes up. Check console for any JS errors. Remove form fields and see if it works. If so, add them back one by one to find the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it appears that for guest you have:

```
= f.link_to_add "Add guest", :guest
```

Yet for room_requests you have:

```
= f.link_to_add "Add room request", :room_requests
```

Try making :room_requests singular => :room_request

Comment: My bad, it should be :guests

Comment: Yes, it is. It's just that I misstyped. It is written in plural and works that way.